# Progressive enlargement of a button in Vuetify when hovered

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions, vuetify.js

I'm trying to have a button enlarging progressively in Vuetify: I start from a fab icon then when I hover the button the text appears. For the moment the text appears progressively, but the button change its size directly from little to big, there is no progression, no animation for the size of the button.
If I didn't explain myself correctly, please ask me for more details.

```js
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    })
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col
              cols="12"
              sm="6"
            >
              <v-hover
                v-slot:default="{ hover }"
                open-delay="200"
              >
                <v-btn
                  color="blue-grey"
                  class="ma-2 white--text"
                  rounded
                >
                  <v-icon dark>mdi-help-circle-outline</v-icon>
                  <v-scroll-x-transition>
                    <span v-if="hover" class="ml-2">Help</span>
                  </v-scroll-x-transition>

                </v-btn>
              </v-hover>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
        
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, try changing v-scroll-x-transition to v-expand-x-transition. Please try, and let us know, if it helped or fulfilled your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing from:

```
<v-scroll-x-transition>
 <span v-if="hover" class="ml-2">Help</span>
</v-scroll-x-transition>
```

to:

```
<v-expand-x-transition>
 <span v-if="hover" class="ml-2">Help</span>
</v-expand-x-transition>
```

With this approach, you will be able to get rid of that "snap", that as you`ve described: from little to big.